# Webpack pass an argument to string-replace-loader

Tags: javascript, webpack, string-replace-loader

Is there any way to pass an argument to the [string-replace-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader) ?

I try to achieve something like that -

Write in the shell - `webpack arg1=HelloWorld`

In the `webpack.config.js` -

```
var value = arg1 // get it from the shell

{
    test: /testFile\.js$/,
    loader: 'string-replace-loader',
    options: {
        search: '$',
        replace: value,
    }
}
```

And `$` in testFile.js would become to be "HellowWorld".

How Could I get that ?

Comment: inside webpack config `module.exports = function(env, argv) {..`, try `argv.arg1 || 'defaultValue'` (or env.arg1)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `argv` or `env`, let's assume you would like to achieve something by running `webpack --env.text=test`, then after executing this in your console, you can access environment variable inside your javascript code, so while you are in testFile.js you can just write:

`console.log(process.env.text); //returns 'test'` and from here you can do whatever you want with that value, perhaps replace $ sign with it, or maybe directly printing it somewhere.

More info here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/